# GameKit authenticateWithCompletionHandler stuck

Tags: iphone, authentication, gamekit

I'm having a classic everything-worked-yesterday-nothing-works-today kinda day.

I set up Game Center yesterday. Managed to log in, get leaderboards, get achievements etc.

Today, everything stopped working. **authenticateWithCompletionHandler** doesn't call the completion handler, even for an error.

I tried several iPhones, rebooting them, rebooting the mac, deleting and installing the app and more (all hints gathered from the internet).

I figured it was a temporary Game Center Sandbox issue, but then noticed it was working fine on the simulator. So  I retargeted my own code, had another reboot, and now it doesn't even work on the simulator!

When I try to open the Game Center App it's in "Loading..." state, and doesn't get out of it.

What am I doing wrong? What happened between everything was working, to nothing is?

Answer (score 0):

Log out of your current GameCenter account in your iphone.. Install the app again and launch the app.. Note that it should prompt you to sign in.. If not, check your codes to ensure that it calls the function to authenticate the user is being called..

Comment: When I opened GameCenter, it was stuck on loading, without an option to Log Out.
But I just reran the code a day after, and everything worked. I think the GC Sandbox was down for maintenance or something.

Comment: Yes, the situtation resolved on it's own - how should I Stack Overflow about it?

Comment: I think Apple often puts their sandboxes in "offline" mode just to give you an opportunity to handle such exceptions in your app. This goes for Game center as well as iAd, IAP and what not. I may be wrong though. Their sandboxes always seem twitchy and the problem might just be real problems :-D

Comment: Are experiencing the exact same problems. Too bad that the solution for you was to just wait.. Hopefully it will start working for me soon :(